# JavaScript events in order

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a button and this button should wrap the text and un-wrap it, how can I make the button un-wrap the text for the first click then the next click wrap it?
Wrapping is done by property `white-space`.

```js
// split the state into two chunks
function fullView(e) {
        // check if the element is the targeted or not
    if (e.target.parentElement.className == 'note') {
          // first state with the un-wrap text
         if(e.target.style.whiteSpace == 'normal'){
         // convert it to wraped
            document.querySelector(".note-content").style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
        }else {
        // convert it to un-warped text
            document.querySelector(".note-content").style.whiteSpace = "normal";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="note">
    <p class="note-content"> 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !! 
        Hello, World Note !!
    </p> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the content of `fullView`, I assume you have it set as a `click` handler on `.note-content`. If so, the simplest way is to define a CSS class:

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

...and in `fullView`, toggle it:

```
function fullView(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle("nowrap");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// split the state into two chunks
function fullView(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle("nowrap");
}
document.querySelector(".note-content").addEventListener("click", fullView);
```

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<li class="note">
                 <p class="note-content"> 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !! 
                    Hello, World Note !!
                    </p> 
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much